# efficient way to use multiple local image resources in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-vectordrawable

I have around 200 images as vector drawables (in res folder) that i'd like to load in recyclerview. Since the size of vector drawable is not that big I've decided to store them inside the app and not set up the server or do api call. The total size of 200 images sums to 4/5 MB only. When I try to show the images in recyclerview it's creating a lag. Since Picasso and Glide are no use for vector drawables what approach would be the best to solve the lag issue? Is paging helpful for local resources?

Comment: You should use Glide and can do lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

The lag is because of the *decoding* of the vector into bitmap on the UI thread. You can read it here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource

Quick solution would be to use any image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) which does this stuff in background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination to avoid the lagging of the images while loading. It will be so fast even the app lifecycle is stopped or destroyed.

[Android Paging Docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)

The Paging Library helps you load and display small chunks of data at a time. Loading partial data on demand reduces usage of network bandwidth and system resources.

Here is the docs for [Paging using RecyclerView](https://androidwave.com/pagination-in-recyclerview/)

I hope it works for you.